# Creating a variable list in tidycensus in R: How to resolve Error in bind_rows_(x, .id)?

Tags: r, tidyverse, census

First time posting, so let me know if there's anything that I can do to improve my question. I'm currently trying to pull some data from the census using tidycensus. To do so, I need to know that names of the variables.
The creator's guide (https://walkerke.github.io/tidycensus/reference/load_variables.html) recommends using this line of code to create a variable list that you can filter:

```
library(tidycensus)
v15 <- load_variables(2015, "acs5", cache = TRUE)
view(v15
```

However, each time I use it, R returns:

"Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 6 must be length 1, not 0"

How do I resolve this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** this is now fixed in the development version of **tidycensus**.  Install from GitHub with `devtools::install_github("walkerke/tidycensus")` and give it a try.  I'll have the updates on CRAN soon.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me as well. Really love the package!

Answer (score 0):

> Update: this is now fixed in the development version of tidycensus. Install from GitHub with devtools::install_github("walkerke/tidycensus") and give it a try. I'll have the updates on CRAN soon.

That worked for me. Thanks! I'm looking forward to using this in a class this fall.